# animated GIFs with Twitter Player card not working?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am trying to set Up Animated GIF with player card. but when I test my player card https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator it dosen't show animated GIF.

Here is my meta code for player card

```
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
<meta name="twitter:card" value="player">
<meta name="twitter:site" value="@uncleLaravel">
<meta name="twitter:title" value="domain.com">
<meta name="twitter:description" value="sample">
<meta name="twitter:image" value="http://domain.com/img/sample.gif">
<meta name="twitter:player" value="http://www.domain.com/container.html">

<meta name="twitter:player:width" value="320">
<meta name="twitter:player:height" value="320">
<meta name="twitter:domain" value="domain.com">
```

container.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<style>
html, body{ margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
img{ border: 0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="gif" src="/sample.gif" width="100%">
</body>
</html>
```

Is anything wrong here?

Comment: Did this work for you? I saw this comment from the Twitter folks saying the Giphy animated gifs were mp4s. https://twittercommunity.com/t/animated-gifs-are-currently-supported-in-twitter-cards-via-the-player-card-but-how/16825

Comment: @treejanitor I have tried without https(NO SSL)  and it's not working. I am not sure about whether it works with https or not.

Comment: I've tried with https for animated gifs, but it doesn't work for me.  I have gotten an mp4 to play successfully though; you need to use their player card and be whitelisted as a domain (apply to twitter for that).  Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

Your example is correct, just make sure all your links are https. If you generate the card data dynamically, remember to set Conetnt-Type to text/html.

Comment: thanks. I don't have SSL currently I will check one I bought.